# GCC x86 assembler function tables

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I'm writing a 6502 emulator in x86 assembly language. The heart of the emulated machine is a 256-entry table of code pointers for each 6502 opcode :

```
fns_asm:
.word opasm_brk         // 0x00 BRK
.word opasm_ora_indzx   // 0x01 ORA (,x)
.word opasm_undef
.word opasm_slo_indzx   // 0x03: SLO (,x)
.word opasm_nop_zp      // 0x04: NOP zp
...

opasm_brk:
< implementation of BRK instruction >

opasm_ora_indzx
< implmentation of ORA instruction >

... etc ...
```

The problem is that the compiled shared library (.so) fails to load at runtime. The error reported on x86 Android is:

> dlopen("/data/app/com.myapk/lib/x86/lib6502.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed:
>   dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "" referenced by "lib6502.so"

Note the empty symbol name, very unhelpful!

I've worked out that my function table is to blame... if I change fns_asm to be a zero-entry table, or to have a single entry with a constant rather than a label (i.e. ".word 0") then the .so loads fine. It's the referencing of labels with .word directives that causes things to go wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A word on x86 systems is 16 bits (unless the GNU assembler has decided to break that convention). You probably want to use `.long` instead.

Comment: That's it, many thanks Michael! I've been using .word because I'm not writing this emulator from scratch, I'm porting ARM assembly code I wrote years ago. Using .long makes everything work fine. Put your comment in an answer so I can give you the points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for `.word`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Word.html#Word) in the GAS manual says:

> The size of the number emitted, and its byte order, depend on what target computer the assembly is for.

I haven't found an authoritative source for the size of a `.word` for different targets. However, the term *word* in the context of an x86 system means 16 bits (in Intel's manual, in the section *Fundamental Data Types*, they say *"a word is 2 bytes (16 bits)"*).

Assuming that you're not writing an emulator to be run in 16-bit real mode you probably wanted your function table entries to be 32-bit. The appropriate pseudo-op to use for that when targetting x86 systems is `.long`.